# In a jQuery revolving content div, how do I make the div always as tall as the tallest content?

Tags: jquery

I'm a bit of a jQuery noob. I know enough to find and implement and do a bit of customization on jQuery plugins I like, but not enough to write my own plugins. I recently found this: http://sandbox.sebnitu.com/jquery/quovolver/ and I really like it, and I'm now using it in a website.

The problem I have is that, as you can see on the example page above, the div containing the quotes changes height based on the height of the content it's currently displaying. When a new quote appears, the height of the div changes with it. How can I determine the maximum height the div WILL be and have it ALWAYS be that height so that content below the revolving quote div never moves up and down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could grab the highest elements hight, and set the height of all the other elements to that height.

In your example, the  elements does not have a class attribute, you should of course add this to them, so all of them looks like this `<blockquote class="quote">Quote</blockquote>`

```
/*Run when the DOM is ready.*/
$(function() {

    //We will populate this variable with the height of the highest quote element
    var heightOfHighest=0;

    //Lets iterate all quote elements, to figure the highest.
    $(".quote").each(function () {

            //If this elements hight is larger than the one already set, we set the variable with the new height
            if ( $(this).height() > heightOfHighest ) {
                heightOfHighest = $(this).height();
            }
    });

    //Now, once again. iterate all quote elements
    $(".quote").each(function () {
        //Set the height of each and every quote object to the same as the highest of them.
        $(this).height( heightOfHighest );
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works great. I did a little extra (with difficulty) to re-call this when the window resizes. But this was a big help and got me down the right path. Thanks!